# void as a type of an argument of a generic function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

It is possible to specify `void` as a type parameter for generic function in TypeScript. And it works fine for return values of functions. However when `void` is a type of an argument it's not that clear what value can be used for it. Is there a way to specify a parameter for an argument of the `void` type? If no, why is it possible to declare such a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out it's very easy to get a value of void. Although technically it is still the `undefined` value, but TypeScript believes it's of the type void which is exactly what we need:

```
var voidValue = (function () { })();
```

Comment: This one is pretty old, but in latest typescript versions you can just `var voidValue: void = undefined;`

Answer (score 12):

From the [TypeScript specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#325-the-void-type):

> NOTE: We might consider disallowing declaring variables of type Void as they serve no useful purpose. However, because Void is permitted as a type argument to a generic type or function it is not feasible to disallow Void properties or parameters.

Answer (score 11):

A useful use for `void` is when you want to make a parameter optional. Angular [uses this](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/4cda0f3404bbb8de4cc9d07fa6dae19af9f7fa78/src/cdk-experimental/dialog/dialog-container.ts) a lot with RxJS `Subject<T>` when emitting events and there's no useful type for the event.

The signature for `Subject<T>`'s `next` function is :

`next(value?: T)`

You can create a `Subject<void>` which makes the `value` parameter forbidden:

`new Subject<void>().next()` // ok

`new Subject<void>().next(true)` // not allowed

as opposed to non-void where you get

`new Subject<boolean>().next(true)`

Not sure exactly which TS version this became possible.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to use `void` as a type argument, but you shouldn't use it as a type.

In fact, although you may be able to use it in a type annotation currently, it is impossible to assign a value:

```
var x: void = ???; // cannot supply a value
```

The use of void as a type argument is illustrated below:

```
class Example<TReturn> {
    process(func: () => TReturn) {
        return func();
    }
}
```

The type argument in this class is used to specify the return type of a function. That means that I may wish to specify that the function will have the `void` type. So it must be allowed as a type argument.

```
var example = new Example<void>();
```

Now when I write the call to `example.process`, auto-completion will tell me that the argument I pass needs to satisfy the following type:

```
func: () => void
```

And it will also tell me that `example.process` itself is void *in this case*.

The intention isn't for `void` to ever be used to annotate a type, but because there are valid reasons to allow it as a type argument it isn't checked currently. It means you can create something invalid, but you'd be hard pressed to use it:

```
class Example<T> {
    process(func: T) {
        // if T is void, this is all wrong
    }
}

var example = new Example<void>();
```

In this invalid example (which doesn't show any errors) you wouldn't be able to write a call to `example.process` because you couldn't pass a valid argument.

Answer (score 8):

You can cast `undefined` to `void`:

```
const x: void = undefined as void
```

Comment: When I pass `undefined`, it works for me without casting.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
class Example<T> {
    process(func: T = undefined) {
    // use default undefined parameter
    }
}

var example = new Example<void>();

exmple.process();
```

I'm using Typescript 1.8.7 and it worked for me fine.

Comment: I get a compiler error -- `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.ts(2322)` -- in the declaration of `process`. I'm using TypeScript Version 3.4.5.

Comment: If I remove the `= undefined` then it works fine -- i.e. I can call `exmple.process()` when `T` is `void` and that would be a compiler error when `T` is `number`.

Answer (score 1):

Like @c-snover said, `void` serves almost no useful purpose but it is allowed as **function parameter type** or as **type argument for a generic type T**, so it cannot be removed from the spec.

**TLDR ⇒** Declaring a `function(v: void)` is like saying `v` is not there. You can though `return d`, which is equivalent to just `return`, but you can't pass any value of any type to that function argument (well, except a variable of type `void|undefined` and value `undefined`).

In the case of generic type arguments, on instantiation, the same rules apply. If `T` is passed `void` on instantiation, whereever the type `T` is used in that class, it's substituted by `void`, so the above applies again.

---

Functionally, `void` is the same as `undefined`, except in some cases where it is implicit, like in function returns when there's nothing being returned.

`undefined` is used implicitly only with optional function parameters (eg. `function(variable?: number)` where `variable`'s type effectively becomes `number|undefined`. If the parameter doesn't get passed any value on a function call, it is implicitly `undefined`.

In contrast a declaration of `function(variable: number|undefined)` would mean that the parameter is now mandatory and it needs to be passed a value explicitly, including explicitly passing `undefined`, if that's what you want.